# Exceção returned null Java Web

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Alguém pode ajudar a solucionar uma exceção que esta sendo gerada em minha aplicação?

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java web, coloquei apenas um `input` e um `selectonemenu` na aplicação para tentar salvar os dados, no momento que clico no botão salvar gera a seguinte exceção:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/private/message/insert_message.xhtml @34,104
>   value="#{messageBean.message.name}": Target Unreachable, 'null'
>   returned null     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'null'
>   returned null     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:192)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:86)  at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
>     ... 41 more

Aqui está minha página xhtml:

```xml
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label">#{bundle['system.ui.label.name']}</label>
               <h:inputText id="message" styleClass="form-control"
                       value="#{messageBean.message.name}" />
     </div>
  </div>
```

E aqui meu managedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "messageBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MessageBean {

    private List<Message> listMessage;
    private Message message;
    private List<Category> listCategory;
    private List<Type> listType;

    @EJB
    private MessageFacade messageFacade;

    @EJB
    private CategoryFacade categoryFacade;

    @EJB
    private TypeFacade typeFacade;


     @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        listAllMessage();
        listAllCategory();
        listAllType();
    }


    public void insert(){

        try {

            message.getUser().getDsUsername();
            System.out.println("Usuario: "+message.getUser().getDsUsername());
            messageFacade.save(message);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Nome" +message.getName());
        System.out.println("Categoria"+ message.getCategory().getName());
        System.out.println("Tipo"+ message.getType().getName());
        System.out.println("Data"+ message.getRegistrationInstant());
        System.out.println("Usuario"+ message.getUser().getDsUsername());
    }

    public void listAllMessage() {

        listMessage = messageFacade.listAllMessage();
    }

    public void listAllCategory() {

        listCategory = categoryFacade.listAllCategory();
    }

    public void listAllType(){

        listType = typeFacade.listAllType();
    }

    public List<Category> getListCategory() {
        listAllCategory();
        return listCategory;
    }


    public void setListCategory(List<Category> listCategory) {
        this.listCategory = listCategory;
    }

    public List<Message> getListMessage() {

        listAllMessage();
        return listMessage;
    }

    public void setListMessage(List<Message> listMessage) {
        this.listMessage = listMessage;
    }

    public List<Type> getListType() {

        listAllType();
        return listType;
    }

    public void setListType(List<Type> listType) {
        this.listType = listType;
    }

    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Comment: Onde você atribui alguma referência para `message`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema é que não está instanciando seu objeto `message`, faça assim:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    this.message = new Message(); /* isso aqui */

    listAllMessage();
    listAllCategory();
    listAllType();
}
```